# Как сделать, чтобы шапка сайта не перезагружалась при переходе по страницам или записям?

Tags: ajax, wordpress

Собственно, вопрос в заголовке. Просмотрел информацию, что это достигается с помощью AJAX. На примере вордпресовских файлов можете подсказать, как это реализовать?

Comment: @harley, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Это легко делается с помощью фреймов, без ajax. Почитайте про FRAME, FRAMESET или IFRAME.